# Can I automatically add functions called using pkg::fct to the importFrom section in roxygen2?

Tags: r, roxygen2

When I write a package, I usually call external functions using `pkg::fct()` just to make it very clear and explicit where the function is coming from. I'm aware of the small overhead, but can usually ignore it.

On the other hand I like it when all external functions appear in the roxygen tags to give an overview of what is used in the function.

Is there a way to automatically add all functions called via `pkg::fct()` to `@importFrom`? And is that a good idea after all?